# Visual Studio 2012 under Windows8: how to prevent copying ASP.NET web site files into user temp folder?

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, visual-studio, windows-8

I have ASP.NET web site (started work on in in VS2008). after I upgraded my machine to Windows 8 Visual Studio started working much slower: each compilation took significant amount of time. If earlier it was 10-15 seconds, now it is 25-50. And VS hangs up during that time.

Eventually I found out what is causing that: **Upon compilation of any project in the solution or of the whole web site, VS copies ALL web site files into temp folder located under user's AppData\Local folder**:

```
C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp719C.tmp.testgen\
```

Totally that is now 35Mb of files, where the biggest is "Bin" folder (20 Mb, 294 files) and folder with pictures (13.1 MB, 2569 files).

And it copies that ton of files on EACH compilation!

That literally takes a half of the minute.

I could delete some picture files (as they represent some business data that are not required during development), but instead I would like to prevent Visual Studio from copying all those files at all.

**Question: How to prevent visual studio from copying all ASP.NET web site files into temp directoty?**

P.S. Now I use Windows 8 (64 bit), Vs2012 update 3, disabled Edit-and-continue. Web site is written using .Net 4.0

P.P.S. VS Also copies a lot of files into another temp folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vfm-elita.com\b5832962\9bb65367), but that looks like a place where all aspx/ascx files are been compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to unit tests project: once I disabled it problem was resolved.

I didn't try to find what exactly is wrong (may be that was just some configuration options). I just created a new project for tests and moved all classes from the old one into a new.